# Decomposition of an element as a difference of positive elements in the definition subalgebra of a weight (Takesaki)

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, weights

I originally asked this on MSE, but did not get an answer there.

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. Let $\varphi: M_+ \to [0, \infty]$ be a weight on $M$. Consider
\begin{align*}&\mathfrak{p}_\varphi:= \{x\in M_+: \varphi(x) < \infty\}\\
&\mathfrak{n}_\varphi:= \{x \in M: \varphi(x^*x) < \infty\}\\
& \mathfrak{m}_\varphi:=\mathfrak{n}_\varphi^* \mathfrak{n}_\varphi=
\left\{\sum_{j=1}^ny_j^*x_j: x_j ,y_j \in \mathfrak{n}_\varphi\right\}\end{align*}

In Takesaki's second volume, chapter VII, (the proof of) lemma 1.9, the following is claimed:

If $x =x^* \in \mathfrak{m}_\varphi$ and $x= u|x|$ is its polar decomposition, then $|x| \in \mathfrak{m}_\varphi$.

**Question**: Why is this the case?

**Attempt**: We have $|x|= x^+ + x^-$, so I tried to show that $x^+, x^- \in \mathfrak{m}_\varphi$. Now, we can write $x=p-q$ where $p,q \in \mathfrak{p}_\varphi= \mathfrak{m}_\varphi^+$ so if we would have $p \ge x^+$ and $q \ge x^-$, we would be done by the hereditary property. I think these inequalities are true when $p$ and $q$ commute, but I don't know if we can choose this decomposition with $pq = qp$.

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Comment: I accepted an edit, which makes an important correction to the definition of $\mathfrak{m}_\varphi$

Comment: @MatthewDaws My definition was also correct. This follows by polar decomposition (see the proof of lemma 1.8 in takesaki, chapter VII).

Comment: Interesting...  Do you know how the proof works?

Comment: I believe that Takesaki meant to write in Lemma VII.1.8, that "every element in $\mathfrak m_\phi$ is the linear span of elements $y^\ast x$ with $x,y\in \mathfrak n_\phi$, the fact driven by the polarisation identity."

Comment: @MatthewDaws I am not 100% sure since I'm new to this stuff, but I posted my own proof in an answer below.

Comment: @JamieGabe I was under the impression that Takesaki was referring to lemma 1.6, chapter VII, which is basically a generalised polar decomposition. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what Takesaki had in mind for the proof, but what you're asking is incorrect. Here is a counterexample where $\phi$ in the counterexample is a normal faithful semifinite (n.f.s.) weight.

Let $H$ be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space, and $M = B(H\oplus H)$. Fix a faithful normal state $\psi$ on $B(H)$ and let $\mathrm{Tr}$ be the standard trace on $B(H)$. Define $\phi ((x_{ij})_{i,j=1,2}) = \mathrm{Tr}(x_{11}) + \psi(x_{22})$. This is clearly a n.f.s. weight.

Fix a positive contraction $a\in B(H)$ which is trace-class but so that $a^{1/2}$ is not trace-class. Let $p = \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & (a-a^2)^{1/2} \\ (a-a^2)^{1/2} & 1-a \end{array} \right)$ and $q= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$ which are projections that are both in $\mathfrak m_{\phi}$. Hence $x=p-q \in \mathfrak m_\phi$ is self-adjoint. A straightforward computation gives $x^2 = \left( \begin{array}{cc} a & 0 \\ 0 & a \end{array} \right)$ and thus $|x| = \left( \begin{array}{cc} a^{1/2} & 0 \\ 0 & a^{1/2} \end{array} \right)$. As $a^{1/2}$ is not trace-class we have $\phi(|x|) = \infty$ so $|x| \notin \mathfrak m_\phi$.

Comment: Very nice. $ \ \ $

Comment: @Jamie Gabe Thanks for the answer! If you allow me to ask a follow-up question: this question was inspired by the proof of lemma 1.9, chapter VII, volume II, p46. I was trying to justify why $h^{1/2}\in \mathfrak{n}_\varphi$. Do you see why this would be true? If necessary, I can ask another question.

Comment: In the language of the proof of Lemma 1.9, $x_0 = uh$ is the polar decomposition, so $h=|x_0|$ and if $h^{1/2}\in\mathfrak{n}$ then by definition $h\in\mathfrak{p}$, which is not so, by this counter-example.  So I don't really follow the proof of Lemma 1.9...

Comment: @MatthewDaws It appears that lemma 1.9 is used in the proof of lemma 1.10, which is used to prove important results later, so it is desirable to find a fix for lemma 1.9. I think I will ask another question.

Comment: But isn't that part of the proof of Lemma VII.1.9 actually easy? With notation from the proof, write $x_0 = y^\ast z$ with $y,z\in \mathfrak n_\phi$. Then $\rho(x_0) = \psi(x_0) = ( a \eta_\phi(z), \eta_\phi(y) ) = \langle a , \theta_\phi(y^\ast z) \rangle \leq \| \theta_\phi(y^\ast z) \| \| a \| \leq \| \theta_\phi(x_0)\|$. The first inequality follows since $a$ and $y^\ast z = x_0$ are self-adjoint. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JamieGabe Yes, I think that works! Then my answer below came to the rescue :P Just weird that Takesaki bothers with polar decomposition then. Thanks again!

Comment: Well, that argument would have worked with a linear combination $x_0 = \sum y_i^\ast z_i$, so strictly speaking it isn't needed. But it's still very neat!

Comment: @JamieGabe Yes you are right.

Comment: @JamieGabe Just to make sure I didn't miss anything: why did you say that the first inequality follows since $a$ and $y^*z = x_0$ are self-adjoint? You don't need this? $\rho(x_0)$ is positive, so $\langle a, \theta_\phi(y^*z)\rangle$ too.

Answer (score 2):

This is a reply to the comments. I didn't have enough space there.

Assume $M$ acts on the Hilbert space $H$.

Let $ \mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{m}, \mathfrak{n}$ as in lemma 1.2, chapter VII of Takesaki. We claim that
$$\mathfrak{m}= \{y^*x: x,y \in \mathfrak{n}\}.$$

Indeed, consider a generic element
$\sum_i y_i^* x_i$  of $\mathfrak{m}$, where $x_i, y_i \in \mathfrak{n}$.

Put $a:= \sum_i x_i^* x_i$ and use lemma 1.6 in chapter VII to write
$$x_i = s_i a^{1/2}, \quad s_i [aH]^\perp = 0.$$

Then
$$\sum_i y_i^* x_i = \sum_i y_i^* s_i a^{1/2} = \left(\sum_i s_i^* y_i\right)^*a^{1/2}.\quad (*)$$
Clearly $a \in \mathfrak{m}\cap M_+ = \mathfrak{p}$ and $a= (a^{1/2})^{*}a^{1/2}$ so that $a^{1/2} \in \mathfrak{n}$. Finally, note that
$$\sum_i s_i^* y_i \in \mathfrak{n}$$
since $\mathfrak{n}$ is a left ideal. Thus $(*)$ shows that every element in $\mathfrak{m}$ decomposes as
$$t^*s, \quad s,t \in \mathfrak{n}.$$

Comment: Thanks!  This seems good to me, and a new fact to file away...

Comment: Yes, I take it back by how I assumed he meant polarisation identity instead of polar decomposition. This is a neat trick.

Comment: Thanks both for the verification.

Comment: Neat trick! $\ \ $